# Scroll Text In Perspective ( Picker iOS Style )

Tags: javafx, scroll, jquery-animate, picker

Is it possible to create the Picker Cylinder with JavaFX Perspective? I was able to do the fade (Top and Footer), but which scroll would be the best?

[Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNdaU.png)

Comment: Looks like a fancy `ListView`.

Comment: Yes, looks. But you probably have a skin...